# Editor with support for mixed spaces and tabs?

Tags: c#, java, c++, windows, text-editor

Is there any text editor (for Windows) which has *good* support for **mixed** spaces and tabs, for languages like C++/C#/Java (and bonus points for Python/Ruby/etc.)?
i.e. Tabs would be used for *indentation*, and spaces would be used for *alignment*.

---

As an example, say `→` represents a tab, `.` represents a space, and `■` represents the current position of the cursor.

If I have the following in my text editor:

```
template<class T1,
.........class T2>
class Foo
{
  → template<int M,
  → .........int N>
  → void foo(int bar,■
}
```

I want to be able to press the <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> key, and see:

```
template<class T1,
.........class T2>
class Foo
{
  → template<int M,
  → .........int N>
  → void foo(int bar,
  → .........■
}
```

after which I should be able to type the next parameter, close the parenthesis, and press <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd>, and have the cursor automatically go back to the correct position, using tabs/spaces as shown:

```
template<class T1,
.........class T2>
class Foo
{
  → template<int M,
  → .........int N>
  → void foo(int bar,
  → .........int baz) {
  →  →  ■
}
```

Of course, if I pressed <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or Shift-Tab or whatever, it should clear to the appropriate stop -- which is probably the beginning of the indent that is of the same type as the current one. And stuff like that.

#### Note:

I realize that many editors (SciTE, Visual Studio, and probably Emacs, Vim, etc.) can be *scripted* with regexes (or crude parsing code) to do something that works, oh, 80% of the time.

But I'm looking for something with hopefully a bit more *robust* support, with lexing support for the current language to figure out what to do. After all, editor mistakes shouldn't be harder to fix than indenting manually in the first place -- otherwise I'd just do it manually instead, and never use the feature!

Comment: @Luiggi: Notepad++ sucks, *especially* in this particular regard. Good question, by the way. I think the problem is that most people don't use this type of indentation (although I like it really much if it lines up like this)

Comment: jozefg: That's unarguably true, but can you point at how this particular problem can be solved in VIM? I'd be interested in that

Comment: 5 minutes into the thread and already theres "<editor> sucks" and "use <editor>" in the comments. Way to derail a legitimate question, folks.

Comment: Using mixed tabs and spaces in layout-sensitive languages like Python is really an error. And in all others, it's just ugly.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Yeah I realized the Python issue after I posted... scratch that then. But I don't really think it's ugly in general -- it actually lines things up quite well. :P

Comment: Just indent with spaces. Tabs are more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @Close-Voter: I'm pretty sure development tools should be on StackOverflow...

Comment: I would have thought given any any decent scriptable editor you would be able to implement this feature as a macro script. Just write a macro script that implements this feature and bind that macro to the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this qualifies to be an answer. However, my [gvim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) with current vimrc does exactly what you are looking for with tabs and spaces.
I strongly recommend using [Gvim](http://www.vim.org/download.php). Its a matter of personal choice, there may be better or worse editors.

You can highlight any language on vim using `se syn=` command

What you won't find is lexing support or the intelli-sense - at lease in usable ways.

Have a look at the screenshot. Here is a link to [vimrc](http://spf13.com/post/perfect-vimrc-vim-config-file) that I have adapted.

**EDIT** I really suspect if there is an editor utopia so to speak. You may have to strike a balance based on "right tool for the job" principle.

[image]

Comment: +1 looks very nice, I'll try and see if I can get gvim working. Thanks!

Comment: I think I got it to work... it'll take me a while to get used to vim :) but I'm liking it! Thanks!

Comment: sorry @Mehrdad - I fail to understand what you want to highlight

Comment: The indentation didn't go back to the parenthesis, is what I'm trying to highlight.